# How use the attributes of a fabricator within the definition of the fabricator?

Tags: fixtures, model-associations, modelattribute, fabrication-gem

I have a `User` and `UserProfile` models. Currently both models have the attributes `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` and they must be the same. Later on I will remove these attributes from `User` but currently I want it that way. A `UserProfile` `belongs_to` a `User`. I have defined the `UserProfile` fabricator like so:

```
Fabricator(:user_profile) do
  first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
  email      { Faker::Internet.email }
  user       { Fabricate :user }
end
```

and the `User` fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  email         { Faker::Internet.email }
  first_name    { Faker::Name.first_name }
  last_name     { Faker::Name.last_name }
  last_login_at { Time.now }
  organization  { Fabricate :organization }
end
```

The problem is that now, when I fabricate a user profile the attributes are not the same:

```
user_profile.first_name == user_profile.user.first_name # => false
```

In the definition of the user profile fabricator I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
user       { Fabricate :user, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email }
```

How can I fabricate a user and a user profile with same attributes without having to replace Faker with hard coded values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to reorganize your user profile a bit and use the data from the user to populate its fields.

```
Fabricator(:user_profile) do
  user
  first_name { |attrs| attrs[:user].first_name }
  last_name  { |attrs| attrs[:user].last_name }
  email      { |attrs| attrs[:user].email }
end

Fabricator(:user) do
  email         { Faker::Internet.email }
  first_name    { Faker::Name.first_name }
  last_name     { Faker::Name.last_name }
  last_login_at { Time.now }
  organization
end
```